# How to change git path from C:\cygdrive\c\

Tags: git, cygwin, notepad++, git-rebase

How to change git path from C:\cygdrive\c... to C:\ or just \cygdrive\c\?

I have setup notepad++ as my editor for git. When i try to perform an interactive rebase (git rebase -i), notepad opens but cannot find the right files for rebasing due to this weird path that include C:\cygdrive\c...

Here is an image of the error message that notepad++ shows...

[image]

Comment: Notepad is NOT a cygwin application and can NOT understand the `/cygdrive`. Use the equivalent windows path

Comment: @matzeri you mean when setting the core.editor variable in git? git config --global core.editor "using windows path here"?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to:

- use bash: `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i`
- use [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) to convert Unix and Windows format paths:

That is:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $(cygpath.exe -w "$*")
```

But for using that for an interactive rebase, you need to follow "[Cygwin git passing wrong path to my editor for commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33271707/6309)" and wrap that line in a shell script.